# Add column in existing MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx

I need to add a column in existing MDX and its values should be 1,1,1,1, and 2,2,2 like below.

```
Top line income                     1
Products (GL)                       1           
Net Interest Income (NII)           1
Non Interest Revenue (NIR)          1
Products ( Non GL)                  1
Net Interest Income (NII)           1
Non Interest Revenue (NIR)          1

WIP (No. of Prospects Logged)           2
WIP (Prospects Total Amount) Exposure   2
WIP (Prospects Total Amount) Deposits   2
Accepted Payouts in Progress (volume)   2
Accepted Payouts in Progress Exposure   2
Approval Rate (%)                       2
Rejection Rate (Not taken up) (%)       2 
...
...
```

How to achieve this in existing query?

MDX:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Measure_Key] AS 
    [ScoreCardMeasures].[ScoreCard].Member_Key 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Measure_Group_Key] AS 
    [ScoreCardMeasures].[ScoreCard].Parent.Member_Key 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Structure_Level] AS 
    [CustomerStructure].[Provincial Structure].LEVEL_NUMBER 
  SET [ReportLevel] AS 
    Filter
    (
      [Report Levels].[Report Level].[Report Level]
     ,
        Cint([Report Levels].[Report Level].Properties("Structure Level"))
      = 
        Cint([Measures].[Structure_Level])
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Sequence] AS 
    [ScoreCardMeasures].[ScoreCard].Properties("Sequence") 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Indent] AS 
    [ScoreCardMeasures].[ScoreCard].Properties("Font Indent") 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Weight] AS 
    [ScoreCardMeasures].[ScoreCard].Properties("Font Weight") 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Header] AS 
    [ScoreCardMeasures].[ScoreCard].Properties("Values Header") 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Header1Caption] AS 
    [ScoreCardMeasures].[ScoreCard].Properties("Header Name1") 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Header2Caption] AS 
    [ScoreCardMeasures].[ScoreCard].Properties("Header Name2") 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Header3Caption] AS 
    [ScoreCardMeasures].[ScoreCard].Properties("Header Name3") 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Actual] AS 
    [Measures].[Measure Value] 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Target] AS 
    [Measures].[Measure Target] 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Average] AS 
    [Measures].[Average Value] 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Measure_Key]
   ,[Measures].[Measure_Group_Key]
   ,[Measures].[Structure_Level]
   ,[Measures].[Sequence]
   ,[Measures].[Indent]
   ,[Measures].[Weight]
   ,[Measures].[Header]
   ,[Measures].[Header1Caption]
   ,[Measures].[Header2Caption]
   ,[Measures].[Header3Caption]
   ,[Measures].[Actual]
   ,[Measures].[Target]
   ,[Measures].[Average]
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,{
    Filter
    (
        [ReportLevel]
      * 
        Order
        (
          Descendants
          (
            StrToMember(@Financial_Measure)
           ,[ScoreCardMeasures].[ScoreCard].[Measure Code]
           ,LEAVES
          )
         ,[Measures].[Sequence]
         ,ASC
        )
     ,
      [Measures].[Active Indicator] <> 0
    )
  } ON ROWS
FROM [ScoreCard]
WHERE 
  (
    StrToMember(@SiteStructure)
   ,StrToMember(@Time)
  );
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't fully understand how you decide if it should be a 1 or a 2 - the question does not make it clear.

If you just want it hard-coded into the mdx then this might be an approach:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Measure_Key] AS 
    [ScoreCardMeasures].[ScoreCard].Member_Key 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Measure_Group_Key] AS 
    [ScoreCardMeasures].[ScoreCard].Parent.Member_Key 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Structure_Level] AS 
    [CustomerStructure].[Provincial Structure].LEVEL_NUMBER 
  SET [ReportLevel] AS 
    Filter
    (
      [Report Levels].[Report Level].[Report Level]
     ,
        Cint([Report Levels].[Report Level].Properties("Structure Level"))
      = 
        Cint([Measures].[Structure_Level])
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Sequence] AS 
    [ScoreCardMeasures].[ScoreCard].Properties("Sequence") 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Indent] AS 
    [ScoreCardMeasures].[ScoreCard].Properties("Font Indent") 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Weight] AS 
    [ScoreCardMeasures].[ScoreCard].Properties("Font Weight") 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Header] AS 
    [ScoreCardMeasures].[ScoreCard].Properties("Values Header") 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Header1Caption] AS 
    [ScoreCardMeasures].[ScoreCard].Properties("Header Name1") 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Header2Caption] AS 
    [ScoreCardMeasures].[ScoreCard].Properties("Header Name2") 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Header3Caption] AS 
    [ScoreCardMeasures].[ScoreCard].Properties("Header Name3") 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Actual] AS 
    [Measures].[Measure Value] 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Target] AS 
    [Measures].[Measure Target] 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Average] AS 
    [Measures].[Average Value] 
  MEMBER [Measures].[1or2] AS 
    CASE 
      WHEN 
          [ScoreCardMeasures].[ScoreCard].CurrentMember
        IS 
          [ScoreCardMeasures].[ScoreCard].[Measure Code].[Top Line Income] 
      THEN 1
      WHEN 
          [ScoreCardMeasures].[ScoreCard].CurrentMember
        IS 
          [ScoreCardMeasures].[ScoreCard].[Measure Code].[Products (GL)] 
      THEN 1
      WHEN 
          [ScoreCardMeasures].[ScoreCard].CurrentMember
        IS 
          [ScoreCardMeasures].[ScoreCard].[Measure Code].[WIP (No. of Prospects Logged)] 
      THEN 2
      WHEN 
          [ScoreCardMeasures].[ScoreCard].CurrentMember
        IS 
          [ScoreCardMeasures].[ScoreCard].[Measure Code].[WIP (Prospects Total Amount) Exposure] 
      THEN 2
    END 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Measure_Key]
   ,[Measures].[Measure_Group_Key]
   ,[Measures].[Structure_Level]
   ,[Measures].[Sequence]
   ,[Measures].[Indent]
   ,[Measures].[Weight]
   ,[Measures].[Header]
   ,[Measures].[Header1Caption]
   ,[Measures].[Header2Caption]
   ,[Measures].[Header3Caption]
   ,[Measures].[Actual]
   ,[Measures].[Target]
   ,[Measures].[Average]
   ,[Measures].[1or2]
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,{
    Filter
    (
        [ReportLevel]
      * 
        Order
        (
          Descendants
          (
            StrToMember(@Financial_Measure)
           ,[ScoreCardMeasures].[ScoreCard].[Measure Code]
           ,LEAVES
          )
         ,[Measures].[Sequence]
         ,ASC
        )
     ,
      [Measures].[Active Indicator] <> 0
    )
  } ON ROWS
FROM [ScoreCard]
WHERE 
  (
    StrToMember(@SiteStructure)
   ,StrToMember(@Time)
  );
```

Comment: Thanks whytheq,

It has worked for me like I wanted. Yes I wanted to hard code the value.
Thanks again for your time.

Actually I have added this column because I want to drill down these values using report. All 1 should come under one + sumbol, all two under another + symbol and so on...

Do you have any idea how can we achieve this in SSRS using this newly added column. We have added this column because all the values were in one column only, So I was not able to group in report level.

Comment: I'm not too up on ssrs but I think the + signs are added as dynamic way of hiding the detail part of the report? In the Tablix Properties - "Display can be toggled by this item" setting ?